# Importing data from an xls file and update Oracle database using JSP

Tags: java, jsp

```jsp
<%@ page language="java" import="java.sql.*" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ page import ="java.util.Date" %>
<%@ page import ="java.io.*" %>
<%@ page import ="java.io.FileNotFoundException" %>
<%@ page import ="java.io.IOException" %>
<%@ page import ="java.util.Iterator" %>
<%@ page import ="java.util.ArrayList" %>
<%@ page import ="javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest"%>
<%@ page import ="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell" %>
<%@ page import ="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow" %>
<%@ page import ="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet" %>
<%@ page import ="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook" %>
<%@ page import ="org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%!
            Connection con;
            PreparedStatement ps = null;
            Statement stmt = null;

            public static ArrayList readExcelFile(String fileName) {
                /**
                 * --Define a ArrayList --Holds ArrayList Of Cells
                 */
                ArrayList cellArrayLisstHolder = new ArrayList();

                try {
                    /**
                     * Creating Input Stream*
                     */
                    FileInputStream myInput = new FileInputStream(fileName);

                    /**
                     * Create a POIFSFileSystem object*
                     */
                    POIFSFileSystem myFileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(myInput);

                    /**
                     * Create a workbook using the File System*
                     */
                    HSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = new HSSFWorkbook(myFileSystem);

                    /**
                     * Get the first sheet from workbook*
                     */
                    HSSFSheet mySheet = myWorkBook.getSheetAt(0);

                    /**
                     * We now need something to iterate through the cells.*
                     */
                    Iterator rowIter = mySheet.rowIterator();
                    while (rowIter.hasNext()) {
                        HSSFRow myRow = (HSSFRow) rowIter.next();
                        Iterator cellIter = myRow.cellIterator();
                        ArrayList cellStoreArrayList = new ArrayList();
                        while (cellIter.hasNext()) {
                            HSSFCell myCell = (HSSFCell) cellIter.next();
                            cellStoreArrayList.add(myCell);
                        }
                        cellArrayLisstHolder.add(cellStoreArrayList);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return cellArrayLisstHolder;
            }%>
        <%
            String file = request.getParameter("file");

            String fileName = "E://Book1.xls"; //Excel File name
            out.println(fileName);
            //Read an Excel File and Store in a ArrayList
            ArrayList dataHolder = readExcelFile(fileName);
            //Print the data read
            //printCellDataToConsole(dataHolder);

            try {
                Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
                con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:dbase", "manav", "pass");
                stmt = con.createStatement();
                String query = "insert into checkers(names,classe,value) values(?,?,?)";

                ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
                int count = 0;

                ArrayList cellStoreArrayList = null;
                //For inserting into database
                for (int i = 1; i < dataHolder.size(); i++) {
                    cellStoreArrayList = (ArrayList) dataHolder.get(i);
                    ps.setString(1, ((HSSFCell) cellStoreArrayList.get(0)).toString());
                    ps.setString(2, ((HSSFCell) cellStoreArrayList.get(1)).toString());
                    ps.setString(3, ((HSSFCell) cellStoreArrayList.get(2)).toString());
                    count = ps.executeUpdate();
                    //out.print(((HSSFCell)cellStoreArrayList.get(2)).toString() + "\t");
                }

                //For checking data is inserted or not?
                if (count > 0) {
        %>

        <!--Following details from Excel file have been inserted in student table of database-->
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Student's Name</th>
                <th>Class</th>
                <th>Age</th>
            </tr>

            <%
                for (int j = 1; j < dataHolder.size(); j++) {
                    cellStoreArrayList = (ArrayList) dataHolder.get(j);%>
            <tr>
                <td><%=((HSSFCell) cellStoreArrayList.get(0)).toString()%></td>
                <td><%=((HSSFCell) cellStoreArrayList.get(1)).toString()%></td>
                <td><%=((HSSFCell) cellStoreArrayList.get(2)).toString()%></td>
            </tr>
            <%}
            } else {%>
            <center> Details have not been inserted!!!!!!!!!</center>

            <%    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }%>
        </table>

    </body>
</html>
```

It just shows a blank page. The xls worksheet is located at E:\. The code is not doing what it is supposed to do. What is causing error?

Comment: This is why you should work with unit test or at least a console app where you test if your algorithm/idea works. And then, use proper MVC: Servlets as controllers, JSP as view, not JSP as a place to drop all the messy code and execute it.

Comment: Review your import statement and really not good practice to code in jsp page !!! Try with suitable MVC pattern !!!